# ReactJS table not rerender when data in state change

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn ReactJS and his reactive behaviour. I have started with a simple example. I have a component with some data as state and I am trying to display them as a table. My code is really simple:

```js
<table>
    {this.props.tableData.map( (row, index) => (
        <tr>
            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.participant}</td>
            <td>{row.status}</td>
        </tr>
    ))}
</table>
```

but when I change the state with setState (I have a button with a clickHandler to do it), my table is not redrawn. I feel like I am missing something obvious, any idea?

Comment: update question with your code of setstate.

Answer (score 0):

@Ved you were right, there was a typo when I was calling the setState (I was actually assing an object to setState instead of calling the function). Should have caught it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. For future reference, these kinds of problems are usually solved right away without any help needed whatsoever when you create a [mcve].